# Hibernate many-to-many join table not populating

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, many-to-many

I want to associate two entity classes User and Unit via a many-to-many association using a join table. However this is not working as intended. First I'll briefly show you what I got so far.

Database:

```
|    User    |   |  UserToUnit   |   |   Unit    |
|Id|login|...|   |User_Id|Unit_Id|   |Id|name|...|
```

Entity User:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "\"User\"")
    public class User implements Identifiable {
        public User() {
            units = new ArrayList<Unit>();
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "guid")
        @Column(name = "Id", columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier")
        private String id;

        @Transient
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name = "UserToUnit",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "User_Id", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
            inverseJoinColumns =  { @JoinColumn(name = "Unit_Id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }
        )
        private Collection<Unit> units;
        [...]
        public Collection<Unit> getUnits() {
            return units;
        }

        public void setUnits(Collection<Unit> ous) {
            units= ous;
        }
    }
```

Entity Unit:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Unit")
@XmlRootElement
public class Unit implements Identifiable {

public Unit() {
    users = new ArrayList<User>();
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "guid")
@Column(name = "Id", columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier")
private String id;

@Transient
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "units")
private Collection<User> users;
[...]
public Collection<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(Collection<User> us) {
    users = us;
}
```

Usage:

```
user.getUnits().add(unit);
unit.getUsers().add(user);
unitDAO.saveOrUpdate(unit);
userDAO.saveOrUpdate(user);
```

But this does not add anything to the UserToUnit table. What am I missing here?
Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the reason why you are using the `@Transient` annotation? You should be using that if you want to use property access and the getter is not following the field name.

You are mixing field and property access, so you should also add `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` to the getter method or move annotations to the field.

Comment: @Transient is for JAXB when serialising the entity to JSON. I don't get your second statement. Please expand. Thx.

Comment: I mistook the annotation for javax.persistence.Transient which would mean that the field will not be persisted. Don't you mean javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient though? I can also see that you have moved annotations to the field so my second comment is now irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are right. Sort of. I mistook the `@Transient` for the `@XmlTransient` annotation. Cheer!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specifie in your `User` class and `Unit` class your ID, to match the attribute that will be join in the `@JoinColumn` annotation.

Can you add to both `User` and `Unit` classes this ?

```
@Id
@Column(name = "Id")
private long id;
```

Comment: That is with in the "[...]" Which I omitted to save space. You cannot have entities without an Id in hibernate.

Comment: Oh, ok.
Does your User and Unit entities work, or you have the same problem as UserToUnit ?

Comment: Added the Id property to my code sample. Also the individual entities work, yes.